# Persisting checked state using localstorage

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have taken the following snippet from a previously asked question on how to store the checked/unchecked status of all checkboxes on a page in localstorage:

```
     $(function(){
        var test = localStorage.input === 'true'? true: false;
        $('[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', test || false);
    });

    $('[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
        localStorage.input = $(this).is(':checked');
        console.log($(this).is(':checked'));
    });
```

When I select one of the checkboxes and then refresh the page, once it reloads every single checkbox is checked.

How would I make this store each individual checked state?

**Note** I may have between 0 - 50 check boxes available depending on how many outstanding records there are in my gridview so I don't have fixed input id's to use only a record id associated to each row.

Comment: You will have to create an array and push it

Comment: @RamanathanMuthuraman could you alter my JS to show me please?

Comment: Without using IDs, how would you 'remember' which ones was checked? Regarding row index or what? Anyway, this would be better to handle it server side, avoiding any client side cache issue

Comment: Would it not be possible to get a handle on the checkbox's value which is the record id: <input id="selectedAddressesIds" name="selectedAddressesIds" type="checkbox" value="18075">

Comment: Each checkbox will have a different value, matching the record id

Comment: @SelectDistinct Sorry for previous removed comment, wrong jsFiddle. Now check this one instead: http://jsfiddle.net/uoL4rtmL/

Comment: @A.Wolff followed the link and checked2 boxes then refreshed, all boxes came back unchecked, am I missing something here?

Comment: @SelectDistinct Sorry, is that fixed it: http://jsfiddle.net/uoL4rtmL/1/

Comment: @A.Wolff Yes, that worked, thanks, you should have written it as an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to rely on a localStorage solution, you may do something like this:

```
$(function(){
    $('[type="checkbox"]').each(function () {
        var $this = $(this),
            name = $this.attr('name');
        $this.prop('checked', localStorage[name] === 'true');
    });
});

$('[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        name = $this.attr('name');
    localStorage[name] = $this.is(':checked');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mct7xgq2/

The first part is executed on page load and sets the checked state depending on the localStorage[name] value, where name is the input's name attribute.

The second part executes when any checkbox is being changed: it takes the input's name, as before, but instead of reading the value, it writes it.

Answer (score 0):

IF the page would not load, it would be better to just store the values in `JS` object rather than using `localStorage` .

Just create a JS object and keep pushing values inside it and store

**Client Side Solution if the page does not reload**

```
    $(function(){
      var checkedItems ={};
        $('[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
               //Store the ID value also in the localstorage
              if($(this).is(':checked')){
          var id = $(this).attr('id'); //Get the id if this is checked
           checkedItems['id_'+id] = id;
              }
        });
   });
```

If Page reloads, then your best bet is to use server side concepts like `Session`.
Send an `AJAX` request each time a particular checkbox is checked and store it in a session.

**SERVER SIDE SOLUTION**

```
      $(function(){
            $('[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
                   //Store the ID value also in the localstorage
                  if($(this).is(':checked')){
                    var id = $(this).attr('id'); //Get the id if this is checked
                    $.ajax({
                          type: 'POST',
                          url: your server side url path, //store it in a session
                          data: {'id':id},
                          dataType: 'html',
                          success: function(result){
                          //so some functionality
                          }
                        });
                  }

            });
      });
```

Check out the [FIDDLE LINK](https://jsfiddle.net/3czjvpyu/5/)

Comment: seems to be a syntax problem with var checkedItems[id] = id;

Comment: corrected it...should not have used "var" keyword while pushing the element inside the object...thanx for notifying :)

Comment: checkout the fiddle link

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution for d3.js with a ternary operator use. It compares the id of this checkbox with the values stored under key=id in localStorage.
If the value is "true" then 'this.checked' is set to 'true', else to 'null' ( null indicates: no 'checked' property)

```
var box = d3.selectAll(".box").each(function(){

      var id = this.id;
      var storageValue = localStorage.getItem(id);

      this.checked = storageValue === "true" ? true : null;

});
```

Previously I have setItem in localStorage. The checkbox are created dynamically appended to rows in a table

```
    rows.append('input')
        .attr('type','checkbox')
```

which in turn is based on the data from a cvs. With the following ids for the checkboxes:

```
.attr("id", function(d,i) { return 'box'+' '+i; })
```

And the 'change' of the checkbox state:

```
d3.selectAll(".box").on("change", function() {

    var id = this.id;

    if ( this.checked ){
    localStorage.setItem(id, this.checked); 
    }

    else  {
    localStorage.removeItem(id);
    } 

  });
```

I have thousands of rows, each with a checkbox. I did not see a major issue on the timeline inspection. So I guess that this is a good solution. I am not a d3.js expert.